# Should I remove Stop words with POS tagging?

Tags: nlp, stemming, chunking, pos-tagger

I'm new to this NLP stuff but all the examples of POS tagging and Sentence Chunking I have seen don't seem to have removed stops words. So question I have if I'm doing POS tagging and Chunking is does this remove the need to remove stopwords (and also Stem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context explaining what you are trying to accomplish, there is absolutely no reason to remove stop words. Most applications where you need POS tags need them for all of the input text, including the stop words.

Comment: Apologies I have inherited a text analytics engine that does theme based categorisation. from what I can tell it does not use either stop words or POS tagger and I'm a) trying to get my head around how all the various NLP components (tokenize, Stemmer, Lemmatisation, Taggers, Chunkers, etc etc) work together (or don't) and b) understand whether we should be using some of these concepts to improve the our categorisation matching. Thanks for the answer it helps and confirms my thinking so far

Comment: Stemming and stop words are techniques for "boiling down" a text to some sort of simplified representation, and is often used for search-related tasks. POS tagging adds more information, e.g. for grammatical analysis. In that sense, these techiques are opposites.

Comment: Thanks this helps allot also and confirms my suspicions that this application actually does two different all though related things i.e. Search based Categorisation for simple keywords and NLP based categorisation themes like Sentiment.

Comment: Is it poor etiquette to expand this question out  or should I raise another Question, to name the processes techniques in NLP that apply to Search (tokenisation, Spell checking, Thesaurus, N-Grams, Stemming, Lemmatisation, lexical Chaining, ...),  the ones that apply to Theme based categorisation (Tagging, Sentence Chunking, Machine Learning, ...), the sequence of steps in each and then how the two different pipelines interact? I've read a lot on this subject over the last 3-4 weeks, but not seen anything that summarises this well i.e. Search and NLP for dummies.

Comment: Start a new question, or, by the sound of it, multiple questions.  A good question has a straightforward (albeit not necessarily short or uncomplicated) answer, and you can mark it as "resolved" once somebody posts something which helps you straighten out your question mark. StackOverflow generally does not tolerate "laundry list" questions very well, so perhaps you should go elsewhere for the overview questions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I probably do some more research and then if needed provide what I think the answer is for review